# BcryptEncoder configuration in Spring Security Configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, bcrypt, password-encryption

So I'm creating this restservice but I am struggling with the encoderconfiguration.

I created a config class to set the passwordencoderBean, as instructed in replies below.

My code compiles. But when I try to log in, I get 'Bad Credentials', and yes I am sure I am using right credentials. Also Yes, the password in my  database is Bcryptencoded with {bcrypt} in front of it. My guess is that I am misconfiguring this passwordEncoder configuration.Where lies the fault in configuration?

Here below my passwordencodeConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class PasswordEncoderConfig {
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

current SpringSecurityConfiguration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    private static final String ADMIN = "ROLE_ADMIN";
    private static final String WORKER = "ROLE_WORKER";
    
    private final DataSource dataSource;
    private PasswordEncoder bcryptencoder;
    
    public SecurityConfiguration(DataSource dataSource,  PasswordEncoder bcryptencoder) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.bcryptencoder = bcryptencoder;
    }
    
    /*@Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }*/
    
    
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select voornaam as username, password as password, true as enabled from gebruikers where voornaam = ?")
            .passwordEncoder(bcryptencoder)
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select voornaam as username, role as authorities from gebruikers where voornaam = ?");
        
            
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
        .mvcMatchers("/images/**")
        .mvcMatchers("/css/**")
        .mvcMatchers("/js/**");
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
        /*remove after postman, @cross origin*/
        http.formLogin();
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
            .mvcMatchers("/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN, WORKER)
            .mvcMatchers("/gebruikers/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN, WORKER));
        http.logout();
        
    }
    


}
```

Comment: Your matchers are also in the wrong order `/**` or `anyRequest` **always** has to be last. The rules are consulted in the order they are defined in. The prefix should be `{bcrypt}` not `{Bcrypt}`. Finally your `SecurityConfiguration` is missing an `@Configuration` and currently won't be used.

Comment: The matchers is done on purpose for now. {Bcrypt}, Typingerror, changed it.  @configuration doesn't change anything.

Comment: Your query uses the `voornaam` column in your database as the `username` not sure if that is correct or if there is another field. Also what is the type of column of both `voornaam` and `password`.

Comment: If adding `@Configuration` doesn't change a thing, there is something else wrong and I wonder if your configuration is even taken into consideration...

Comment: Yes it all worked just fine when using {noop}passwords. I just have problems  since I hashed the passwords and added the passwordEncoder. They are both Strings.

Comment: If it fails with the encrypted one is the string used for the password correct? Is it in there in its complete form or are there parts missing? Or maybe a trailing space etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to go is to use

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
{
    return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}
```

It uses BCrypt as the default but provides a better interface for future migration. Note that the generated password has a prefix:

```
With Factory:
{bcrypt}$2a$10$Zz3xIJON0d1GI0vqMULIKOHCImVnFCWMNRE3Vw0ElvSmfCqGcDV5W

Without:
$2a$10$Zz3xIJON0d1GI0vqMULIKOHCImVnFCWMNRE3Vw0ElvSmfCqGcDV5W
```

When you use the factory and provided a bcrypt hash without the prefix, it will be rejected as invalid.

Edit: And as Chaosfire said it, you defined a circular bean definition. Instead of injecting it to a field, you can use the method for the bean declaration, spring will inject the instance to the method call, so you end up with the same password encoder, which you provided at the bean declaration.

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
        .usersByUsernameQuery("select voornaam as username, password as password, true as enabled from gebruikers where voornaam = ?")
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder()) // referencing bean, not field
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select voornaam as username, role as authorities from gebruikers where voornaam = ?");
```

Comment: I have a without {bcrypt} now, I used  "bcrypt.encode(originalPassw)" to create it and got  it without the {bcrypt}. I assumed that would be good since it was created by Bcrypt itself.

Comment: When you don't override the bean for the password encoder, spring will use the factory. Take a look at `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.LazyPasswordEncoder#getPasswordEncoder`

Comment: And it requires the prefix, otherwise, two bcrypt encoded passwords would differ.

Comment: Still have the same problem, bad credentials. I'm gonna update my question.